# Detect if a webpage has programming code on it

Tags: html, parsing, web, heuristics

What is the best way to detect if a web page is a programming tutorial?

This means that a web page has programming code in its content. E.g. http://www.djangorocks.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-basic-blog-in-django/starting-your-application.html

Comment: What do you mean all webpages have code on them?

Comment: updated. e.g. http://www.djangorocks.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-basic-blog-in-django/starting-your-application.html

Comment: Why is this a problem which you want to solve? What sort of classification accuracy would you consider acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

If a webpage is using proper semantic HTML then you can parse it for the 'code' element. However this doesn't sure that you will find all web pages that are presenting code as readable content.

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code

Comment: An awful lot of sites use `<code>` just for its formatting properties. It predates any semantic markup initiatives by a large margin. Also, even a lot of semantically motivated uses are other types of code than program code (configuration data, markup examples, etc).